# On permutation notation

Tags: notation, permutations

I am trying to write up a proof that the parity of permutations on finitely many letters is well-defined. I think I have a proof that involves the number of disjoint cycles that a permutation may be written as. Is there a standard notation for the number of disjoint cycles in a permutation on finitely many letters?